# How to access a variable using content of another variable as name?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would access the value of a variable. The name of the variable I want to access is stored in another variable and/or passed by argument to the batch.

So, I want to achieve two things:

1. calling batch with desired variable name as argument (and batch accessing the var directly):

   --> command line==batch.bat myVar

   {batch file:}
   echo (what is in variable myVar)
2. calling batch with variable name that holds another varibale's name and output that other variable:

   Let's assume that the variable "var_name" exists and has the value "APPDATA"

   --> command line==batch.bat var_name

   {batch file==}
   echo (what is in variable APPDATA)

Comment: In a batch file, [`%~1`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) returns the first argument (your string `myVar`), `!%~1!` expands a variable (the value of variable `myVar`; given that [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled); `for /F "delims=" %%V in ("!%~1!") do … !%%V!` introduces another level of expansion (returning the value of `AppData` in your second example); this could also be nested, like `for /F "delims=" %%V in ("!%~1!") do for /F "delims=" %%W in ("!%%V!") do … !%%W!`, and so forth…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure why you need this, but I am assuming you want something like:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "var=appdata"

for %%i in (!%1!) do (
   echo original val from variable "%1" = "%%i"
   echo secondary val from variable "%%i" = "!%%i!"
)
```

Here, I have set a temp value for `var` to be `appdata`. When running `scriptname.cmd var` you'll get the relevant results for both variables `var` and its value `appdata`